# Нужен совет по разработке сайта под мобильные устройства

Tags: php, html, css

**Здравствуйте!** Выручите пожалуйста советом по разработке сайта под мобильные устройства. В интернете информации на счёт данной темы катастрофически не хватает. Заранее благодарен. Буду рад любому совету, как по вёрстке, так и по разработке серверной части (PHP).

Comment: @angers777, Перефразируйте, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос: исправьте грамматические ошибки, правильно расставьте запятые. Если ещё добавите побольше уточняющей информации, то Вы ускорите получение ответа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По верстке: Верстайте как для десктопа, но под меньшее разрешение и максимально резиновый макет. Картинок - минимум, все же понятие "трафик" и "медленный интернет" для мобильных устройств все еще актуально.
Элементы управления делайте большие, с учетом того, чтобы на экране 3-3,5" они были соизмеримы с пятном контакта пальца(тачскрин же!)
Яваскрипт и CSS3 используйте с осторожностью: много чего в портативных браузерах еще нет(временно).

По серверной части: сервер должен отдавать ответ быстро и только по-делу, чтобы, опять-таки, минимизировать трафик. Остальное устройству должно быть параллельно.

Последнее: если это мобильное приложение, которое обращается к серверу, не используйте стандартные HTTP соединения, используемые для обращения к веб-страницам, так как они обязывают разрывать соединение по завершении, а у некоторых операторов каждый коннект карается "минимальным порогом", порой до 100кб. 10 коннектов - уже метр набежал.

Comment: Спасибо, полезные советы